# JSPM and Typescript import

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I'm trying to get working Angular2 with Typescript and SystemJS but I'm experiencing troubles with imports.

With this import (or with any other angular2 imports)

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
```

I'm getting Webstorm and tsc compiler errors (WS: cannot resolve directory, tsc: Cannot find module) even though there is angular2 in **jspm_packages/npm/angular2@2.0.0-beta.0**

my directory structure is

```
browser
    components
        app.component.ts
    bootstrap.ts
    index.html
node_modules
jspm_packages
jspm.config.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
    "!./jspm_packages/**/*.ts",
    "./**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

and config in jspm.config.js

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    transpiler: "typescript",
    paths: {
        "github:*": "../jspm_packages/github/*",
        "npm:*": "../jspm_packages/npm/*"
    }})
```

This code somehow works, but compiler seems confused, is there a better (or right) way how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible in Webstorm 11. There is a workaround which actually works, see David Festen's comment at: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18904.

By the way, please +1 this issue, maybe that helps speeding things up for Jetbrains to come up with a fix.